# Trying to read into a file and then overwrite the file, replacing old data with new data

Tags: python, function, loops, file

My goal is to take an existing file which contains names and scores of students in a class, and replace each student's score one by one. Firstly I open the file in read mode and create a dictionary for the student, then ask for a new score from the user and replace the value in the dictionary. Then what I want to do is replace the lines in the file with the new scores, however I can only manage to add them onto the existing scores.

This is my code:

```
def editStudent(classfile):
    with open(f'Class {classfile}.txt','r+') as file:
        studentNo = int(file.readline())
        data = file.readlines()
        for i in range(0,studentNo):
            piece = data[i]
            contents = piece.split(',')
            name = contents[0]
            score = contents[1]
            readin = {}
            readin[name] = int(score)
            replacement = int(input('Please enter a new score for ' + name + ' > '))
            readin[name] = int(replacement)
            for key,value in readin.items():
                studentdata = '{},{}\n'.format(key, value)
                file.close()
                with open(f'Class {classfile}.txt','w') as file:
                    file.write(str(studentNo) + '\n')
                    file.write(studentdata)
```

This is what the text file looks like:

```
2
Max Sinclair,100
Random Guy,50
```

The first line of the file specifies the number of students in the class, a variable I use to create a loop inside of my function to tell the program how many students are needed to be replaced.

This is the output when I run the program and input new scores for each student:

```
2
Max Sinclair,100
Random Guy,50
Max Sinclair,99
Random Guy,49
```

Comment: `open(f'Class {classfile}.txt','w')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to re write the all file you need to open it with 'r' first, then close it with .close() then re open the file with 'w' to write on the file. 
When you write on a file who isn't empty, you erase all it content.

Comment: This kind of works, however only the last student in the list is being written to the file.

Comment: @sliceabled you can write the first one with 'w' to erase the text then adding the others with 'a'